# Maven not adding Main-Class to manifest

Tags: java, maven, manifest

I'm learning how to use Maven and I can't compile project with "java -jar ...." because it's showing error about no main manifest. If i add manualy to Manifest.mf:

```
Main-Class:  path to class
```

it is working. I already added this to my pom.xml but still not working

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.kijak.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-app</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.kijak.app.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I see my problem. When i Was adding plugin to pom.xml I changed groupId and artifactId to my project name, didn't realised that's maven plugin name :D I am happy that i figured it out on my own haha!